# Java Socket not allowing swing frame to show up

Tags: java, swing, sockets, jtable

Hey all I am at a loss as to why its doing this. If I just run the server and standalone client it works just fine. However, once I use my code for the client it seems to get stuck...

```
static JTextField textField         = null;
static JTextArea messageArea        = null;
static String serverAddress         = "localhost";
static UFTtrack window              = null;

public static JFrame frame;
public ImageIcon[] images;
static JTable table;
Date lastUpdate;
static Timer timer;
static Scanner in;
static PrintWriter out;

public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @SuppressWarnings({ "static-access" })
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(new MaterialLookAndFeel());
                } catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }

                try {
                    window = new UFTtrack();

                    placeChatOnScreen();
                    createTable();
                    SystemTrayz.createTray();

                    centreWindow(frame);
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

public UFTtrack() {
   initialize();
}

private void initialize() {
        frame = new JFrame("UFTtrack");
        frame.setTitle("UFT Tracker");
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setSize(1308, 900);
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        frame.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(1308, 900));
        frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1308, 900));
        frame.setLayout(null);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
    }

@SuppressWarnings({ "resource", "unused" })
private static void placeChatOnScreen() {
    try {                       
        textField = new JTextField();
        textField.setFont(new Font("Segoe UI", Font.PLAIN, 13));
        textField.setDragEnabled(true);
        textField.setBorder(new MatteBorder(1, 1, 1, 1, (Color) new Color(0, 0, 0)));
        textField.setBounds(338, 838, 954, 22);
        frame.getContentPane().add(textField);

        messageArea = new JTextArea();
        messageArea.setEditable(false);
        messageArea.setFont(new Font("Segoe UI", Font.PLAIN, 13));
        messageArea.setBorder(new MatteBorder(1, 1, 1, 1, (Color) new Color(0, 0, 0)));
        messageArea.setDragEnabled(true);
        messageArea.setName("chatArea");
        messageArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        messageArea.setBounds(338, 648, 954, 181);
        frame.getContentPane().add(messageArea);

        textField.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                out.println(textField.getText());
                textField.setText("");
            }
        });

        Socket socket = new Socket("localhost", 8877);

        in = new Scanner(socket.getInputStream());
        out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);

        while (in.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = in.nextLine();

            if (line.startsWith("SUBMITNAME")) {
                out.println(getName());
            } else if (line.startsWith("NAMEACCEPTED")) {
                textField.setEditable(true);
            } else if (line.startsWith("MESSAGE")) {
                messageArea.append(line.substring(8) + "\n");
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

It does fine until it gets to the "NAMEACCEPTED" else if condition and it just steps out of the while loop and then nothing happens. No error of any kind. It just doesn't how the swing frame!

If I comment out:

```
/*while (in.hasNextLine()) {
    String line = in.nextLine();

    if (line.startsWith("SUBMITNAME")) {
        out.println(getName());
    } else if (line.startsWith("NAMEACCEPTED")) {
        textField.setEditable(true);
    } else if (line.startsWith("MESSAGE")) {
        messageArea.append(line.substring(8) + "\n");
    }
}*/
```

and run it the swing frame loads up just fine. But my Socket (which I am wanting in my swing app) keeps it for some reason passing.

```
window = new UFTtrack();

placeChatOnScreen();
createTable();
SystemTrayz.createTray();

centreWindow(frame);
window.frame.setVisible(true);
```

To sum all this up - the above code hits the **window = new UFTtrack();** and **placeChatOnScreen()** but after it exits the **While loop** in the **placeChatOnScreen()** it never continues to **createTable();** What's the deal???

Also posted here:

> http://www.javaprogrammingforums.com/whats-wrong-my-code/41820-java-socket-not-allowing-swing-frame-show-up.html#post165295
>   https://coderanch.com/t/708072/java/Java-Socket-allowing-swing-frame
>   https://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/415549-java-socket-not-allowing-swing-frame-to-show-up/
>   [Java Socket not allowing swing frame to show up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55435803/java-socket-not-allowing-swing-frame-to-show-up)

Comment: Because the socket is waiting for data/more data?

Comment: The Socket is created on the Event Dispatch Thread (EDT). A Socket blocks while it is waiting for data, so the EDT can't respond to events or paint the GUI components. You need to create a separate Thread for the Socket, so the blocking is done on that Thread.

Comment: @camickr is it possible for you to provide an example as the answer?

Comment: I don't have an example handy. Did you try searching the forum/web for examples. Maybe key works like "Socket Thread Swing" will provide examples that use both classes.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments `read` and `accept` operations typically block on a `Socket`.

You could create an own `Thread` which is waiting for Message from your `Socket` and then modify the GUI. Keep in mind that Swing is not Thread safe.

If I need to create an own `Thread`, I use the `Runnable` interface. You could achieve it like this:

```
public class MySocketListener implements Runnable {

    private final GUIClass guiClass;
    private final ServerSocket serverSocket;
    private Socket clientSocket;

    public MySocketListener(GUIClass guiClass, ServerSocket serverSocket) {
        this.guiClass = guiClass;
        this.serverSocket = serverSocket;
    }

    /* Everything that happens in this method, is done on another Thread. */
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try{
            this.clientSocket = this.serverSocket.accept();
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(this.clientSocket.getInputStream());

            while(true) {
                /* Blocking operations */
                this.guiClass.doSomething();
            }
        } catch(IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The `Thread` can then be started easily:

```
Thread socketListenerThread = new Thread(new MySocketListener(this, serverSocket));
socketListenerThread.start();
```

For more information have a look at the [Thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html) and [Socket](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html) documentation.